# Confused about a withdraw function in a contract I am studying

Tags: solidity

I am fairly new to Solidity and at this point, reviewing contracts that are active and on chain. I am trying to understand every detail. This withdraw function has got me stumped.

```
    function withdraw(address token, uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
        if(token == address(0)) { 
            payable(_msgSender()).transfer(amount);
        } else {
            IERC20(token).transfer(_msgSender(), amount);
        }
    }
```

Particularly the two parts that are "if(token == address(0))" and "payable(_msgSender()).transfer(amount);".
The best explanation for address(0) is here [What is address(0) in Solidity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219716/what-is-address0-in-solidity) but I have to admit, both answers have me bewildered.
I have read that payable() is casting the address to be payable and that this has been deprecated. Just looking for a short explanation as if to a child.

A decent amount of time searching to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code seems to aim to be an universal function for two separate features:

1. withdraw native token
2. withdraw ERC-20 token

If you pass `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` as the value of `address token`, the code transfers `amount` of native token from the contract balance to the `_msgSender()` address. Each network has usually different native token - ETH on Ethereum, BNB on Binance Smart Chain, MATIC on Polygon, ...

If you pass any other value as `address token`, the contract assumes that there's an ERC-20 contract on that address, and tries to transfer out `amount` of the ERC-20 token from the contract balance to the `_msgSender()` address.

---

`payable` extension of `address` is not deprecated. Since Solidity v0.8.0, all native transfers need to be performed to an `address payable` type - while older versions also allowed transfers to the regular `address` type.

The use of `transfer()` function might be a bit confusing, though. When it's called on an `address payable` type, it's the native transfer. And when it's called on an `interface` or `contract` type (in your case `IERC20`), it invokes a function on the specified contract - in this case the external contract function is also called `transfer()`.